# Showing Navagation for External users with Document Library access only

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, navigation

Is it possible to have the navigation menus displayed for external users who are only given permissions to document libraries?  I would prefer to keep them without any access to the parent team site, but still want them to see the navigation menu.  I have tried turning off audience targeting but that was unsuccessful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the user has no access to the site/list/library/page, he cannot view the link of this site/list/library/page in the navigation. The link will disappear if he does not have any access to it. It is impossible to display all links in the navigation for the user has not access.

As a workaround, you can insert links to the page.